# three.js - create draggable circle

Tags: webgl, geometry, three.js

I've just cloned the three.js project from github. I'm interested in creating a circle on a 2d plane that I can drag with my mouse. I have no experience in graphics programming (WebGL or OpenGL).

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've tried google, but the examples seem too complicated.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something you need to have a go at. It's not nearly as complicated as you might think. If the maths are scaring you off, don't worry three.js handles it all for you, you just need to add a camera, some shapes and ask it to render them.

Please do take the time to go through [aerotwists three js tutorials](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/) as these will give you a good grounding in how to setup a basic scene.

You will quickly realise that once you have a scene you can change objects quite easily using your current scene.

As for dragging things around, I'm sure that will come just try to walk before you can run.